# Why doesn't HashMap recognize its key, if the key is a String Array?

Tags: java, hashmap

Let see these codes:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> testTree = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();                
String k = new String("1");
String v = new String("2");
List<String> children = new ArrayList<String>();
children.add(v);
testTree.put(k, children);
if (testTree.containsKey("1")){
    System.out.println("found!!");
}
else
    System.out.println("No found!!");
```

Output1: `found!!`

```
HashMap<String[], List<String[]>> testTree2 = new HashMap<String[], List<String[]>>();                    
String[] k2 = {"1","2"};
String[] v2 = {"2","3"};
List<String[]> children2 = new ArrayList<String[]>();
children2.add(v2);
testTree2.put(k2, children2);

String[] k3 = {"1","2"};
if (testTree.containsKey(k3)){
    System.out.println("found!!");
}
else
    System.out.println("No found!!");
```

Output2: `No found!!`

Why does output1 is "found" & output2 is "No found"? It means HashMap doesn't recognize its key if the key is a String array, but if the key is a String then it will be fine.

I have a need to put a String array into the key of HashMap, so how can we let HashMap to recognize the String array key?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (testTree2.containsKey(k2)){`

Comment: I am very sorry , pls check the code again as i have just modified it.

Comment: I believe this falls under the category of a typo question?

Comment: Hi people, pls check again.

Comment: It's "String[] k3", i am very sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that an array is a new instance of `Object` and even if two arrays has the same number of elements, their hashcodes will be different.

In short, using an array as key of a `Map` (`HashMap`, `LinkedHashMap`, etc) is a bad idea. Use a different key instead.

Answer (score 3):

`HashMap` uses `equals(Object obj)` and `hashCode()` method to save and retrieve objects from `HashMap`, String class overrides these methods while String[] is an object and it wont so after putting it in HashMap, for String[] `hashCode()` and `equals(Object obj)` defualt's implementation  by Object class is ran, which cause un predictable results

Comment: `for String[] hashCode() and equals(Object obj) defualt's implementation by Object class is ran, which cause un predictable results` Your explanation is all over the place. As long as you pass in the same reference to the array, it will work. Of course, in practice, since array's `hashCode` is based on the reference, using array as key makes it impossible to retrieve the value by key unless you have the same reference to the array.

Comment: String and Wrapper Classes are good to use as key because they are immutable.

Comment: @MinhHai: Practically, I don't know whether there is any use case with array as key in HashMap. If you want to retrieve the value, whose **content** of the key is the same as the one your provide, then plain array should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

Variable name is wrong. Change `testTree` to `testTree2` in the if condition

```
            HashMap<String[], List<String[]>> testTree2 = new HashMap<String[], List<String[]>>();                  
            String[] k2 = {"1","2"};
            String[] v2 = {"2","3"};
            List<String[]> children2 = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            children2.add(v2);
            testTree2.put(k2, children2);

            if (testTree2.containsKey(k2)){
                System.out.println("found!!");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("No found!!");
```

Comment: Hi Craign, i am vey sorry, pls check the code again as I modified it